# php - Function results prints in wrong location

Tags: php

I am working on a small php project. 
I have a function to get first image of many. Here it is.

```
function firstImageThumb($condb, $pid){
    $image2 = mysqli_query($condb, "select * from product_images where pid = '$pid' limit 1" );
    $imgD2 = mysqli_fetch_array($image2);
    //$printImage = '<img src="../../thumbnails/'.$imgD['image_name'].'">';
    $printImage2 = $imgD2['image_name'];
    echo $printImage2;
}
```

When a user search something, the following code executes.

```
$sql = "SELECT pid, product_name, product_code FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '" . $query . "%' OR product_code LIKE '" . $query . "%'";
    if($result = mysqli_query($condb, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      echo "<div id='searchr'><table width='99%' class='table'><thead><tr><th></th><th>Product</th><th>Product Code</th></tr> </thead><tbody>";
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               $img = firstImageThumb($condb, $row['pid']);
               echo "<tr><td><img src='thumbnails/".$img."'></td><td>".$row['product_name']."</td><td>".$row['product_code']."</td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</tbody></table></div>";
                // Close result set
                mysqli_free_result($result);
```

The problem is, the image path returned from my function should print inside the  tag. 
But it prints top of the div. Please see the below image.

[image]

Comment: Don't `echo` in the function `return`. Also parameterize your queries.

Comment: @user3783243 - parameterize means?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

In the function `firstImageThumb()` it directly echoes out the image name.  This is when the function is called which is why it gets output first.

As you already are expecting the function to pass the name back just change

```
echo $printImage2;
```

to

```
return $printImage2;
```